# a modification problem

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Above all, effective executives treat change as an oppotunity rather than a threat. *They systematically look at changes*, **inside and outside the corporation**, and ask "how can we exploit this change as an opportunity for our enterprise"?

The emphasized part is used to modify changes or look at? My thought is that for the latter, because the comma here serves as a mark to sever the emphasized part from the unit that is closest to the comma, namely changes. But I find some repetition in meaning if taking the strong part as adverb to modify look at. It is a question puzzling me quite a few hours. Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: I don't see that it makes any difference. If they are looking both inside and outside, the changes they are looking at may be inside or outside!

Comment: It's an adjunct (modifier) in (and thus part of) the VP "systematically look at changes inside and outside the corporation".

Comment: It's ambiguous. In principle the two meanings are different (are these effective executives systematically looking for "leverageable" changes ***when they're not at work***, or are they looking at changes ***happening outside the company***? But in practice the difference isn't likely to be significant (the point is ***they're always on the lookout***), so it doesn't really matter how you parse it.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence isn't clear, but it seems likely that they intended for "inside and outside the corporation" to modify "changes." In context, they are saying that they don't just look at changes inside the corporation; they also look at changes outside of the corporation. They aren't doing the looking *from* "inside and outside" the corporation, since during this activity the executives are *always* inside their company.

The commas aren't necessary here; in fact, they only make the sentence more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Modify schmodify...

This is a parenthetical phrase.  So it may be omitted. It just adds extra information.  Which changes (specifically) do effective executives look at?  Is it only those inside the corporation? Is it only those outside the corporation?  No! It is both those inside and outside the corporation.

So there is in implied noun "changes" which is modified by this phrase. But trying to identify modified elements doesn't always lead quickly to an understanding of the sentence.